# function declaration isn’t a prototype

Tags: c, errno, gcc8

The following code compiles fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int errno ;

int main ( void )
{
    FILE *fp;
    int errnum;
    fp = fopen ("testFile.txt", "rb");

    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        errnum = errno;
        fprintf( stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno );
        perror( "Error printed by perror" );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errnum ) );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    fclose ( fp );
}
```

But I can not compile it with:

```
gcc-8 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes
```

I get the following:

```
 program.c:6:1: error: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes]
 extern int errno ;
 ^~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

How can I avoid/fix this? I need this compiler flag `-Wstrict-prototypes`

Comment: You should *never* declare `errno` yourself. It doesn't *have* to be a variable (it could be a macro that calls a function, which is very common).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
extern int errno ;
```

is wrong. You should simply remove this line.

What's going on is that you're including `<errno.h>`, which defines a macro called `errno`. Well, actually ...

> It is unspecified whether `errno` is a
>   macro or an identifier declared with external linkage. If a macro definition is suppressed
>   in order to access an actual object, or a program defines an identifier with the name
>   `errno`, the behavior is undefined.

(That's from C99, **7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`**.)

In your case `errno` probably expands to something like `(*__errno())`, so your declaration becomes

```
extern int (*__errno());
```

which declares `__errno` as a function (with an unspecified parameter list) returning a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Well you are right, and the manual says: **Do not do this**  ===>>  `On some ancient systems, <errno.h> was not present or did not declare errno, so that it was necessary to declare errno man‐
       ually (i.e., extern int errno).  Do not do this.  It long ago ceased to be necessary, and it will cause problems with  mod‐
       ern versions of the C library.`
You can add this to your Answer if you want to.

Comment: By the way, you was right , this compiles fine ==>> `extern int (*__errno(void));` (I will not use it)  which makes your Answer to be True.